# Unable to drag and drop Components in same Droppable react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

What's happening is when I have multiple items in a column and attempt to drag one, only one is shown and according to the lessons found [here](https://egghead.io/courses/beautiful-and-accessible-drag-and-drop-with-react-beautiful-dnd) I should be at the point where I can move items within the same column but can not. In React dev tools state and r-b-dnd ids look good, but what do I know? I'm just a rookie. Here is what I have in my `onDragEnd` so far.

```
  onDragEnd = result => {
    const { destination, source, draggableId } = result;
    if (!destination) return;
    if (
      destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    ) {
      return;
    }
    let start = this.state.list[source.droppableId];
    let finish = this.state.list[destination.droppableId];
    if (start === finish) {
      let updatedList = this.state.list.map(obj => {
        if (obj.id === source.droppableId) {
          obj.cards.splice(source.index, 1);
          obj.cards.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId);
        }
        return obj;
      });
      this.setState({ list: updatedList });
    }
```

And my app can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rmpmn17kp). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, in `onDragEnd` you have this code which is why you can't rearrange items on same list. When you move items across same list, source and destination Droppable IDs will be same.

```
if (destination.droppableId === source.droppableId && destination.index === source.index) {
  console.log("they're equal");
  return;
}
```

2. On your  component, the dragabble ID is same for all items in the list. It should be unique for every draggable item.

```
const Card = props => {
  return (
    // This is NOT unique. This should be dynamic, we should use idx probably.
    <Draggable draggableId={props.col + "-" + props.color} index={props.idx}>
      {provided => (
```

After correcting these two, Im able to move items: https://codesandbox.io/s/r5z28w85yo. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: YES! Thanks so very much. Is there anything else I should be careful of? I think the tutorial is a little dated but basically it's just applying the correct state for the move... right?

Comment: I think your code is good. We just need unique identifiers for draggables and droppables. And I didn't see the logic for moving between the lists - is that not part of your requirement?

Comment: Yes but again I'm new at this so if you look @ my onDragEnd it's just what I could glean from the video lesson to that point. I was thinking something similar to what I have to move cards between columns.